# Will there be a candidate questionnaire for the upcoming election?

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

The [announcement for the *pro tempore* moderator elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections) says:

> For these elections, the candidate questionnaire is an optional feature that individual sites can choose if they want (example here). If sites choose not to have a questionnaire, we encourage voters to ask their questions on the site's meta

Will we have a candidate questionnaire for this election? Is there still a decision to be made on this, and/or what questions should be on it?

Comment: Yeah, this kinda came out of left field (CMs normally tell mods what the election schedule is and Politics wasn't on it). What I would say is we need to have a quick questionnaire (2 days of [featured]) and then present it to the candidates.

Comment: Question collection is [now up over here](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4559/what-should-be-on-the-moderator-candidate-questionnaire)